# What is the equivalent to .contains for string buffers

Tags: java

What is an equivalent way to use .contains when using a StringBuffer?

For example, with a String you could write

```
String word = "word";

if(word.contains("w") {
//Does something
}
```

But if you change word into a StringBuffer, you get an error that reads: "The method contains(String) is undefined for the type 
StringBuffer"

How would I be able to code the same line but with word as a StringBuffer?

Comment: `if (word.indexOf("w") >= 0)`

Comment: Use `StringBuilder`, not `StringBuffer`. It is the modern replacement.

Answer (score 8):

The `contains(String str)` method can be easily made by checking if `indexOf(String str)` returns a value that indicates that the substring is in the string it is called on.  If the index returned is `-1` then the substring is not within the searched string, but it is other wise.  `StringBuffer` does not have a contains method, but it does have an indexOf method.  So, if the string code was:

```
String str = "word";
if (str.contains("w")){
    //Handle it here
}
```

then the corresponding StringBuffer code would be:

```
StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer("word");
if (strBuffer.indexOf("w") != -1){
    //Handle it here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("buffercontent");

assertTrue("Message doesn't contain (" +  content+ ")", result.toString().contains(content));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Also, you should check how to format your posts properly here 
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code